# How to select a particular choice from a list of results using php

Tags: php, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

im new to php and i wanna ask how to select particular choice out of many choices like the following

[image]

After clicking it the more info link, it will show more details of the selected choice. Im not using any framework so the code might be messy.the following code is meant for that image.

```
<?php 
require 'connect.php';
$query = "select company_id, company_name, contact_person, telno,email from company";
$result = pg_query($db, $query);

if(!$result){
echo "nothing to show";
}else{

while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
echo"<div class='panel panel-default'>";
echo"<div class='panel-heading' name='company_name'>".$row[1]."</div><div class='panel-body'>";
echo "<p>Contact Person:". $row[2]."</p>";
echo "<a href='more_info.php?cid=$row[0]'>More Info</a></div></div>";
}
} 
pg_close($db);
?>
```

Comment: just use a where clause using the id of the selected row

Comment: the code is meant for the image. i just updated it. Sorry for the confusing statement. now the problem is how to get the particular row?

Comment: a simple link should suffice: `<a href="more_info.php?cid=<echo the company id here or the primary key>More Info</a>"`, then let `more_info.php` handle that specified row from there (usually thru `$_GET` variable), thats where the `WHERE` clause should come in

Comment: another question, how do `$_GET`  the`company_id` into more_info.php?

this is my code in home.php:
`echo "<a href='more_info.php?cid=$row[0]'>More Info</a></div></div>";`

code in more_info.php:
`$company_id = $_GET['$cid'];
 $query = "select company_name, contact_person, telno,email from company where company_id ='".$company_id."'";
 $result = pg_query($db, $query);`

like this?

Comment: .... don't use `$_GET['$cid']` in more_info.php use just `$_GET['cid']` which is what you are sending

Comment: Thank you @Ghost for the guidance Thank you once again~!!

Comment: @Terminus Thanks for the hint which solve my problem. Thank you once again!!!

Answer (score 0):

this problem has been solve thanks to @Ghost and @Terminus enlightenment. The following is the code

in home.php

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
echo"<div class='panel panel-default'>";
echo"<div class='panel-heading' name='company_name'>".$row[1]."</div><div class='panel-body'>";
echo "<p>Contact Person:". $row[2]."</p>";
echo "<a href='more_info.php?cid=$row[0]' class='btn btn-info pull-right'>More Info</a></div></div>";

}
```

in more_info.php

```
#require 'connect.php';
$company_id = $_GET['cid'];
$query = "select company_name, contact_person, telno,email from company where company_id ='".$company_id."'";
#$result = pg_query($db, $query);
echo $query;
```